# Getting subviews of type UIView in loop of cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

```
for progressView:UIView in cell.IBimgCellImage.subviews as UIView{
    //do something
}
```

But getting error,

**Type 'UIView' does not conform to protocol 'SequenceType'**

Is there any way to get rid of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cast is wrong, subviews is an array of UIView, so use [UIView]

```
for progressView:UIView in cell.IBimgCellImage.subviews as [UIView] {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest this simplier approach:

```
for progressView in cell.IBimgCellImage.subviews {
     let aSubView = progressView as? UIView
     //do the work    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5. In this instance, it's okay to force unwrap `parent` because it's known that the parent `UIViewController` will not be nil. It also removes the need to force cast to a `[UIView]`.

```
for subview in parent!.view.subviews {
    // perform action
}
```

Here's an example:

```
for subview in parent!.view.subviews {
    if subview is UIButton {
        subview.isHidden = false
    }
}
```